# How do I Install SpriteBuilder?

Tags: github, spritebuilder

I am trying to follow MakeSchool's Online Academy for iOS game development, and the second step is to download SpriteBuilder from the app store. Since it's no longer on the app store, I know it is on GitHub but I have no experience with GitHub and have no idea how to download and install it. Can someone please walk me through? I'm a complete noob; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [url of github repo](https://github.com/spritebuilder/SpriteBuilder), on the top right side you have a big `Download ZIP` button, click it(no need to use git as you probably won't even use it).

Now find some `README`, most likely on that repo page will be at the bottom(under repo files), read it because it will contain instructions for installing that program.

Extract the content of a .zip somewhere and use the instructions. Pretty easy, isn't it?

Also, don't forget to either write an issue on that page, or directly to someone who works with the source you are going to download if something weird comes up.

Or basically download [GitHub for Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), open Git Shell and go as the `README` tells you.